# Annotation error on modal

Tags: angularjs

I am getting an annotation error because of my modal, I am not sure how to properly inject '$modalInstance'.

below is the code for my modal.

```
function mainModal(header, body, confirmText) {
    var PageCtrl = thisCtrl;

    $uibModal.open({
        'controller': function($uibModalInstance) {
            var thisCtrl = this;
            function sendCancel() {
                var data = {
                    'token': PageCtrl.reservation.token
                };
                ViewReservation.cancelText = confirmText;
                MyApi.reservation.cancel(data).then(function() {
                    $uibModalInstance.close();
                    $location.url('account/reservation/cancel');
                }); 
            }
            function nevermind() {
                $uibModalInstance.close();
            }
            thisCtrl.nevermind = nevermind;
            thisCtrl.sendCancel = sendCancel;
        },
        'controllerAs': 'ModalCtrl',
        'template': 
            '<div class="modal-header">' +
                '<button ng-click="$dismiss()" type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>' +
                    '<h1>' + 
                        header +
                    '</h1>' + 
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="modal-body">' +
                '<p>' + body + '</p>' +
            '<div id="modal-footer">' +
                '<div ng-click="ModalCtrl.nevermind()"  class="nevermind-button">Nevermind</div>' +
                '<div ng-click="ModalCtrl.sendCancel()" class="confirm-button">Yes, cancel</div>' +
            '</div>' +                  
            '</div>',
        'size': 'sm'
    }).result.then(function() {

    }, function() {
        $location.url('account/reservations');
    });
}
```

I have referenced [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296961/angular-bootstrap-modal-causing-strict-di-error-not-sure-why)but am not sure how to properly implement it, as the controller of this modal and it's functions are key/values.

I have tried:

```
function mainModal(header, body, confirmText) {
    var PageCtrl = thisCtrl;

    $uibModal.open({
        'controller': function($scope, $modalInstance) {
            var thisCtrl = this;
            $scope.sendCancel = function() {
                var data = {
                    'token': PageCtrl.reservation.token
                };
                ViewReservation.cancelText = confirmText;
                MyApi.reservation.cancel(data).then(function() {
                    $uibModalInstance.close();
                    $location.url('account/reservation/cancel');
                }); 
            },
            $scope.nevermind = function() {
                $uibModalInstance.close();
            }

            thisCtrl.nevermind = $scope.nevermind;
            thisCtrl.sendCancel = $scope.sendCancel;
        },
        'controllerAs': 'ModalCtrl',
        'template': 
            '<div class="modal-header">' +
                '<button ng-click="$dismiss()" type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>' +
                    '<h1>' + 
                        header +
                    '</h1>' + 
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="modal-body">' +
                '<p>' + body + '</p>' +
            '<div id="modal-footer">' +
                '<div ng-click="ModalCtrl.nevermind()"  class="nevermind-button">Nevermind</div>' +
                '<div ng-click="ModalCtrl.sendCancel()" class="confirm-button">Yes, cancel</div>' +
            '</div>' +                  
            '</div>',
        'size': 'sm'    
    }).result.then(function() {

    }, function() {
        $location.url('account/reservations');
    });
}
```

but cant figure out where to do the `ModalCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$modalInstance'];` without getting an error that either breaks the page or says that '$modalInstance' is not defined. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you already injected it on this line -> `'controller': function($scope, $modalInstance) {`

Comment: I thought so too but I still get an undefined for $modalInstance when the sendCancel function is called

Comment: what is your code now? the first one or the second one?

Comment: I noticed in your second code, you injected `$modalInstance` but in your sendCancel function you used `$uibModalInstance`

Comment: Good eyes, but unfortunately, it still does not work. I get the error `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <- UserReservationCtrl <- UserReservationCtrl`