# Invoking in strict mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have configuration object:

```
jwtOptionsProvider.config({
        tokenGetter: (store) => {
            return store.get('token');
        },
        whiteListedDomains: ['localhost']
    });
```

But, I have strict mode enabled and get the following error:

> tokenGetter is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode

I know about `$inject`, but how to use it properly in this situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular bootstrap modal causing strict-di error, not sure why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296961/angular-bootstrap-modal-causing-strict-di-error-not-sure-why)

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```js
jwtOptionsProvider.config({
    tokenGetter: ['store', (store) => {
        return store.get('token');
    }],
    whiteListedDomains: ['localhost']
});
```

See https://github.com/auth0/angular-jwt#i-have-minification-problems-with-angular-jwt-in-production-whats-going-on

Answer (score 0):

My soulution:

```
function tokenGetter(store) {
    return store.get('token');
}

tokenGetter.$inject = ['localStorageService'];

jwtOptionsProvider.config({

    tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
    whiteListedDomains: ['localhost']
});
```